# Change class bottom element during scroll depending in section

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
var nav = $("#navbar").offset();
var $contentDivs = $(".division");
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $contentDivs.each(function(k) {
        var _thisOffset = $(this).offset();
        var _actPosition = _thisOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (_actPosition < nav.top && _actPosition + $(this).height() > 0) {
            $("#navbar").removeClass("light dark").addClass($(this).hasClass("light") ? "light" : "dark");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    right:20px;
    height:100px;
}
#navbar.light {
    color:black;
}
#navbar.dark {
    color:white;
}
.division {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    height:700px;
}
.division.dark {
    background:black;
}
.division.light {
    background:#f2f2f2;
}

#contact-info{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:30px;
    right:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   
<div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span id="current"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-info">+48 444 112 222</div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
</div>
```

I want to Change class bottom element during scroll depending in section. Bottom element have `position:fixed`. I made it same for top element - that was easy... but when element is fixed on bottom.. Im mad with that. Can u help?

HTML

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   
<div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span id="current"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-info">+48 444 112 222</div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var nav = $("#navbar").offset();
var $contentDivs = $(".division");
$(document).scroll(function() {
    $contentDivs.each(function(k) {
        var _thisOffset = $(this).offset();
        var _actPosition = _thisOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop();
        if (_actPosition < nav.top && _actPosition + $(this).height() > 0) {
            $("#navbar").removeClass("light dark").addClass($(this).hasClass("light") ? "light" : "dark");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#navbar {
    position:fixed;
    top:10px;
    right:20px;
    height:100px;
}
#navbar.light {
    color:black;
}
#navbar.dark {
    color:white;
}
.division {
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    height:700px;
}
.division.dark {
    background:black;
}
.division.light {
    background:#f2f2f2;
}

#contact-info{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:30px;
    right:20px;
}
```

I want to Change class bottom element during scroll depending in section. Bottom element have `position:fixed`. I made it same for top element - that was easy... but when element is fixed on bottom.. Im mad with that. Can u help?

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? Do you want the scroll to be above the fixed-bottom element?

Comment: @Anjs I want #contact info which has bottom position to also add DARK or LIGHT class at the same time as #brand

Comment: Plz include the complete code.

Comment: Code above the post

Comment: I have no idea how make its this same effect for #contact-info... because it's on fixed bottom position.

Comment: @Simon Is this what you want: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/LYbVgXJ

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal 
it doesn't work when the sections are of different heights ...

Comment: I'd like # contact-info to change when it's on a .divider section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add css rules for `#contact-info` with classes `.light` and `.dark` . Like this:

```
#contact-info.dark {
    color: white;
}

#contact-info.light {
    color: black;
}
```

In jquery, do it by analogy, declaring `$("#contact-info")` with the coordinate method:

```
var cont = $("#contact-info").offset();
```

This is the complete code:

```js
var nav = $("#navbar").offset();
var cont = $("#contact-info").offset();
var $contentDivs = $(".division");
$(document).scroll(function () {
    $contentDivs.each(function (k) {
        var _thisOffset = $(this).offset();
        var _actPosition = _thisOffset.top - $(window).scrollTop();

        if (_actPosition < nav.top && _actPosition + $(this).height() > 0) {
            $("#navbar")
                .removeClass("light dark")
                .addClass($(this).hasClass("light") ? "light" : "dark");
        }

        if (_actPosition < cont.top > 0) {
            $("#contact-info")
                .removeClass("light dark")
                .addClass($(this).hasClass("light") ? "light" : "dark");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
    height: 100px;
}
#navbar.light {
    color: black;
}
#navbar.dark {
    color: white;
}
.division {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 700px;
}
.division.dark {
    background: black;
}
.division.light {
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

#contact-info {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 20px;
}

#contact-info.dark {
    color: white;
}

#contact-info.light {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ecdc7512a9.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
   
<div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <i class="fa fa-bars  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <span id="current"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-info">+48 444 112 222</div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
    <div class="division light"></div>
    <div class="division dark"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. That solution not working. Check full page this Snippet... the phone number should change with the beginning of the "light" or "dark" section

Comment: @Simon, This solution does not work correctly if you resize the browser window yourself. But if you immediately run this code on the desired (large) window screen, then the code will work.

Comment: how to add listener to this solution to working for mobile and desktop all time without refresh?